# cannot bind 'std::basic_istream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream<char>&&'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

i have this c++ code snippet which works fine in visual studio but gives error in gcc. Any suggestions are welcomed on how to make it work ?

```
  template <typename ConvertType>

  inline bool Parse(const std::string& input, ConvertType& output)
  {
    std::stringstream stream(input);
    stream.imbue(std::locale::classic());
    return (stream >> output) != NULL;      
  }
```

I am getting this error :

```
./Configuration/Option.h:32:38: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_istream' lvalue to 'std::basic_istream&&'
/usr/include/c++/4.6/istream:852:5: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_istream& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream&&, _Tp&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits, _Tp = Color]'
```

Comment: How do you call to `Parse`?

Comment: what do you want to do by comparing (stream >> output) != NULL; ?

Comment: it's a garbled way of writing `return stream >> output;`

Comment: Which line is line 32?

Answer (score 2):

`(stream >> output)` returns a reference to a stream and it cannot be compared to `NULL`. You can simply return

```
return (stream >> output);
```

which will test a stream by a call to `operator void*() const` (`explicit operator bool() const` in C++11) which invokes `fail()` function to test if operation succeeded.

Comment: That explains why I can't find the `operator void *()` in N3337 :) However, g++ in C++11 mode still accepts `(stream >> output) != NULL`, should this be considered a compiler bug?  It also accepts `static_cast<void *>(std::cout)`